# Disable horizontal scrolling without using overflow hidden property

Tags: html, horizontal-scrolling

My html code [here](http://pastebin.com/rX9bZLkU) and

screenshot 
[image]

How do I remove the horizontal scroll bar with out using: `style="overflow-x:hidden;"` property ?

Comment: PS you have an extra closing <div> in your HTML code link.

Comment: overflow-x:none !important;

Comment: @eddwinpaz: that didnt work ,

Comment: Problem Solved.
The footer was **not inside a container div**. So putting it inside a **div class="container"** solved my issue. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
The footer was **not inside a container div**. So putting it inside a **div class="container"** solved my issue. Hope this helps someone.